# Bootstrap Modal Button Can't Autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a confirmation dialog with modal dialog from Bootstrap. I was add "autofocus" attribute for the"Yes" button. But when the dialog show, the button can't set as autofocus. 
I have try this code:

```
$('.modal').on('shown', function () {

    $("#btnYes").focus();

});
```

But also didn't work for me.

If you have any solution, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap 3.0+ try this:

```
 $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

Also check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940423/autofocus-input-in-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: hai sir, do you have any idea to navigate button with navigation keyboard?

Comment: I am not familiar with navigation keyboard. What is that exactly?

Comment: FWIW, the bootstrap 3 event is 'shown.bs.modal' (not 'shown').  I have edited the answer appropriately